# How to have multiple instances of MATLAB save the same file simultaneously

Tags: matlab

I am currently writing code to run a series of time-consuming experiments using nodes on a Unix cluster. Each of these experiments takes over 3 days runs on a a 12-core machine. When each experiment is done, I am hoping to have it save some data to a common file.

I have a slight issue in that I submit all of my experiments to the cluster at the same time and so they are likely to be saving to the same file at the same time as well.

I am wondering what will happen when multiple instances of MATLAB try to save the same file at the same time (error/crash/nothing). Whatever the outcome, could I work around it using a try/catch loop as follows:

```
n_tries = 0;
while n_tries < 10
    try
        save('common_file',data)
        n_tries = 10;
    catch
        wait_time = 60 * rand;
        pause(wait_time);
        n_tries = n_tries+1;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend against this.  It's much safer to have each node write to a unique file, and then have an additional script that combines them all into one.  This unique file can be given a name based on the current system time or the machine name.

Comment: **NOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!** don't do that!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't.

All Matlab functions are explicitly **not** safe to use in a multi-threading/processing environment.
If you write to one mat-file simultaneously from multiple matlab sessions, chances are good that either several variables are missing (because e.g. 2 matlab append to the same state of the file) or the whole file gets corrupted.

Save individual files and merge them in a post-processing step.

Comment: Yep - you will spend some time writing merge script (depending on the structure) but it is worth it. And it is a good idea to save some unfinished data time to time as well (from experience)

Answer (score 3):

For such long simulation runs, don't aggregate your data automatically unless you have a reliable framework. There are several reasons:

- Out of Memory exceptions or similar while writing can destroy all previous results, this is likely to happen while writing large amounts of data.
- Coding errors can destroy previous results. Your code will overwrite at least the most recent added data in case of a collision.
- Undetected errors in mex functions, which by randomly hit the matlab address space instead of casing a segmentation fault, can cause Matlab to write crap to your Matfile and destroy previous results.

Use some unique pattern, e.g. pc-name + current date/time

Answer (score 0):

You would be best served by having a single *recorder* task that does the file output and queue the save information to that task.

Don't forget that the output "file" that you supply to the matlab only has to be *file like* - i.e. support the necessary methods.